# Session Timeout with AJAX redirects to login page only a partial view/Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need a session timeout for an asp net core website. The intention is, after X minuts without any user's action, when the user would makes some action that requires a request, the website will redirect the request to *Login Page*. As I've read in other posts, I create, in the **ConfigureServices** function in *startup.cs* this portion of code:

```
         services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "_aspnetCoreSession";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

In the same file (*startup.cs*) in the function **Configure**:

```
        app.UseSession();
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            string CurrentUserIDSession = context.Session.GetString("token");
            if (!context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/Index") && !context.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUserIDSession))
                {
                    var path = "/Index";
                    context.Response.Redirect(path);
                    return;
                }
            }
            await next();
        });
```

This works fine unless in the AJAX calls. In the AJAX calls, the request only modifies one component and the *Login Page* is loaded inside this component:

[image]

I understand that the request only modifies the component. My question is if exists some other instruction similar to *context.Response.Redirect(path)* that lets me submit all the page or, if it's not possible, if exists some similar alternative that works when using AJAX calls for timeouts?

Comment: do you mean that `context.Response.Redirect(path)` does not work for ajax requests? that sounds strange, if you use jQuery, at least it just works. I believe the standard javascript `XMLHttpRequest` should handle it that same way.

Comment: @King King In the Ajax success function I have `code`document.getElementById('partial').innerHTML = result; `code` and the redirection changes de result value (not redirects all page)

Comment: The original result's value it's a partial view.